# 'F' key is being overridden to instead full screen embedded video

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, plasmo

My chrome extension uses a content script to embed a button that on click, expands into a AI chat box. The website that I am using this on, Coursera, overrides any input of 'F' into the chat box and instead full screens the embedded video. Looking to disable this or a way around it.

I have tried to instead make the chat box a pop up window, however I can't seem to make it show the contents. My chat box is in a .tsx file and importing it into a HTML that's opened in the new window did not work. I am using the Plasmo framework.